# Is it possible for a nonzero symmetric $2 \times 2$ matrix to have this property? Prove it

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

The matrix $$ A=\left[
    \begin{array}{cc|c}
      1&-1\\
      1&-1
    \end{array}
\right] $$ has the property$$A^2=0$$ Is it possible for a nonzero symmetric 2x2 matrix to have this property? Prove it

I was practicing some exercises for my exam soon, but this caused me doubt and I want to see your answer.Thanks in advance.

Comment: What did you try yourself?

Comment: Hint if $A$ is symmetric try to use  the spectral theorem...

Comment: Take $$  B = \left( \begin{array}{cc} b & c \\ c & d \end{array} \right), $$ calculate $B^2,$ and see what conditions this enforces on $b,c,d$ when $B^2 = 0$  NOTE: you need to use real numbers, it is possible to get $B^2 = 0$ if $B$ is complex symmetric.  JUST DO IT.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the comment above, you can solve this problem by looking directly at the matrix. Let $B= \begin{bmatrix}a&b\\b&d\end{bmatrix}$ be a symmetric matrix. Then $B^2= \begin{bmatrix}a^2+b^2&ab+bd\\ab+bd&b^2+d^2\end{bmatrix}.$ In particular, if $B\neq 0$, it means that at least one of $a,b$ or $d$ is not $0$, thus either $a^2+b^2 \neq 0$ or $b^2+d^2 \neq 0$. Hence $B^2 \neq 0$.

Answer (score 0):

Guide:

If such a matrix $A$ exists, $A$ must have rank $1$.

$$A=auu^T$$

where $a$ is a non-zero scalar and $u$ is of length $1$.

Try to get a contradiction from here.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, because:

A real symmetric matrix $A$ may always be diagonalized by some orthogonal matrix $O$:

$O^TAO = O^{-1}AO = D, \tag 1$

where $D$ is a real diagonal matrix.  We have

$A \ne 0 \Longleftrightarrow D \ne 0; \tag 2$

thus $D \ne 0$ and so

$D^2 \ne 0, \tag 3$

since $D$ is diagonal; so, since

$A = ODO^T, \tag 4$

we have

$A^2 = ODO^TODO^T = ODIDO^T = OD^2O^T \ne 0, \tag 5$

which answers the question in the negative.

It is worth noting that the above applies to matrices of any size.

Answer (score 0):

Actually - as currently stated - the answer to your question is affirmative by the virtue of $$\begin{pmatrix}1&i\\i&-1\end{pmatrix}.$$

The answer is negative if you restrict yourself to real matrices or you replace symmetric by [hermitian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hermitian_matrix). Hermitian matrices are diagonalizable and a nilpotent diagonalizable matrix is clearly zero, because all eigenvalues are zero. Note that for real matrices, symmetric and hermitian are the same notion.